# WP7 Strange thing maybe from ControlToolkit Reply Quote Delete Edit

Tags: windows-phone-7, controls, toolkit

I have a project which i'm working on my office, copying to Skydrive and continue in my home.
Everything worked fine until i added WrapPanel when i was in my office. When I opened the project in my home the app stops working in the debuger after the splashscreen to the System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
When i'm building the app i get success, but the program not running and stoping in the same line. I think something its wrong with the WP7 control toolkit because when i'm open a form without any control ofthe toolkit, everything is working.
I tryied to download again the toolkit and in my home computer and when i'm running the samples I get the error 
Error   307 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.CultureInfoExtensions.Weekdays(System.Globalization.CultureInfo)' and 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.CultureInfoExtensions.Weekdays(System.Globalization.CultureInfo)'  D:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Windows Phone 7\WP7 Toolkit\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit\DateTimePickers\RecurringDaysPicker.cs  160 28  Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit
Same project works fine on my office pc
How can i clean up the bad references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like You've got it added twice but each is looking at different locations on disk.

I'd chek the references in the projct and make sure you've only got the library listed once and then check the hint path to see where that's looking.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled everything and now its working. I couldnt do it in a different way